# Performance and Algorithms for Pattern Matching, With Wildcards

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pattern-matching, wildcard, complexity-theory

I'm trying to determine the best way to implement a pattern matching algorithm for a particular use case. I'll give a bit of an abstraction of what I'm trying to do.

I would like my algorithm to be able to search a sequence of characters, and find the first match to a particular pattern. There are a few subtleties. Firstly, the characters may occur in any order. Additionaly, the pattern may contain wildcards, and there may be multiple types of wildcards.

For example, suppose we have a pattern ?A ?G ?G, where the ? denotes that the proceeding character is a wildcard. Thus, the pattern is looking for the first match for any character and two repeated characters, occuring in any order. We could then have a sequence "ABCDEFF". Doing a depth first search as a tree, the algorithm would find the match AFF. Note that for a sequence FABCDEF, we would also find the match AFF, as the order isn't important.

I've estimated that this would have a runtime of about O(n m!), where n is the pattern length and m is the sequence length. Obviously, this isn't ideal for searching a long sequence. I was just wondering if there was a clever or best way of implementing this, or if there are any sort of mimoisation techniques etc that would increase the speed of the algorithm.

Comment: Another way to phrase your example is to find a character that occurs at least twice, and a different character that occurs at least once (or is there the possibility for one that occurs 3 times), with some particular rules that I hope you can express unambiguously to determine precisely which characters to pick (based on the order they occur in the string) if there are multiple options that would satisfy the required numbers of characters? ... If so, that's not really pattern matching and is a whole lot simpler.

Comment: Given the pattern `?A?G?G` and the sequence `TSRYYT`, what is the answer? And why?

Comment: What about the same pattern and `TTTS`? What about non-wildcards, can wildcards match them? Are there other kinds of wildcards?

Comment: @moreON I'm not sure how that would really be the simple case. For more context, I'm doing tensor algebra. I would imagine that the non-commutative case would be the simple case, as there are literally few possible ways to match a pattern. Then I could certainly reduce the complexity by preprocessing or something for example. The commutative case would then be more computationally complex. If I'm mistaken, could you please explain why? What bound would you place on the complexity.

Comment: @user3386109 Obviously it would be dependent on the implementation, but one would assume a sensible implementation would find TYY as the first match. In a naive implementation ?A matches T, the first ?G matches S, then the 2nd ?G finds no matches, so the 1st ?G moves to R, etc until ?G -> Y ?G -> Y is matched. My question is whether or not there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @btilly ?A ?G ?G would match TTT.  I'm not quite sure what you mean. Our expression will never have wildcards, only the pattern will. There are as many wildcards as needed by the user, for example ?A ?B, ?e ?f, ?\Gamma ?/omega etc can all be used to denote a wildcard.

Comment: One approach is to compute the histograms. The histogram of `TSRYYT` is R:1 S:1 T:2 Y:2, and the histogram of AGG is A:1 G:2. Then the problem is a set cover problem. G:2 is covered by T:2 or Y:2, and A:1 is covered by every letter in the sequence.

Comment: @user3386109 This could work. There would be a few subtleties given my use case, but I think this would definitely be a good starting point for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no truly efficient solution to your problem.

We can demonstrate this by reducing the [3-partition problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) to it.  Given a  multiset `S` of `n = 3 *m`  positive integers summing to `n*T` we can have `n` different letters, each occurring `T` times.  Your pattern will contain `3*m` wildcards, each repeated as many times as the corresponding integer in `S`.  There is a way to match the pattern to the string if and only if there is a 3-partition of `S`.  And therefore a solver for your problem can be used to solve the 3-partition problem.  That makes it NP-hard.  But solutions for your problem that say which letters match to which wildcards can be verified in polynomial time.  Since verification is in P, your problem is actually NP-complete.

In practice, a greedy solution may be good enough.  Create a histogram for the string.  Create a histogram for the pattern.  Try matching the largest bucket for the histogram to the smallest bucket in the string that can match it.  Keep going until you succeed or fail.

If you want better, I'd suggest following the suggestion in the comments to use an integer solver for the set cover problem.